# Lubuntu Linux wont boot after installation

Tags: linux, boot, usb, installation, lubuntu

I'm not the first one having this issue but all these articles dont bring me any further because I am completly new to this Linux *Universe*.

I just installed ubuntu on my Laptop, which works perfectly fine. Later I installed Ubuntu on my Desktop as well(Worked just fine, but was neither smooth nor fast) So I searched for a lighter version-->Lubuntu.So I got the ISO file, made a bootable USB(with Rufus)and did the ususal installation stuff(BIOS Boot Order etc.)

When I booted from the USB error messages appeared for a short amount of time, saying:

```
print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

But the Installation Process afterwards worked fine.

After the Installation finished it told me to restart my PC to finish the setup.In the shutdown screens the error above appeard again but it shuts down.

When it was starting up again it booted from the USB again which was my fault because I left in the first place in the boot order, so I changed that. And removed the bootable USB.
So it tried to boot from the Hard Disk, obvioulsy that didnt work because it trys to boot over network a few moments late which isnt supposed to work so I was left with a black screen telling me:

```
PXE-E53: No boot file received

PXE-M0F: Exiting Boot Agent
```

It's a pretty old desktop so I am not sure if it just cant handle the USB Boot and needs a disk but that would not make sense because it worked fine with Ubuntu.j

Is it possible that there is something wrong with the Boot USB or the ISO File? Or is it just something the boot agent messed up?

If you need me to provide further details or Hardware Specs of the Desktop, let me know.

Thank you all in advance.

---

### **Edit:**

I tried an older version of lubuntu today(Lubuntu 18.04) which worked and rebooted fine after installation so i suppose its a problem with the Lubuntu 19.04.

The first ISO file(The one which wont work)
was the 64bit AMD64 Version

*lubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso*

The other one with 18.04 was the Intel x86(32bit)

*lubuntu-18.04-alternate-i386.iso*

Maybe the PC is just to old for the 64bit system
even though it supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your boot order priority in your BIOS.  PXE errors means it is trying to boot off the network, not the disk.  Since you are not - and probably never will - boot from the network, it might be best to simply disable PXE/network booting in BIOS.  The FD0 error looks like the computer thinks there is a floppy disk drive, as well.  It wouldnt hurt to disable that, as I doubt you are using floppy disks.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I already put the Hard Disk in the Boot Order above Network or floppy disk and since its the only Hard Drive connected it will be in the first place in the boot order for hard drives.But I could try disableing them both.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: if I boot lubuntu (With the USB inserted so it will boot from it again)I get in the installation menu again(Obviously) but its second screen gives me the options:Start lubuntu, test memory, test disk for defects and Boot from first Hard disk. I tried  the last one which made my HDD doing loud noises and then telling me: BOOT ERROR.

Comment: I tried it and disabled Boot from Network as well as the floppy disk controller.It's telling me: _No_ _bootable_ _device_ -- _insert_ _boot_ _disk_ _and_ _press_ _any_ _key_.is it possible that someting with the boot medium is wrong, I mean I had around 10 try to get it running and each time i get to the installation process in the disk partitioning it tells me that my disk currently hold Ubuntu 19.04 which I had before.

Comment: If your hard disk is making "loud noises," it might be dying.  Test the disk for errors.

Comment: I did test it a few installations ago where it  was fine. Maybe getting formatted all the time isnt that healthy. But an older version of Lubuntu boots just fine